# Determine if Docker image is signed or unsigned

Tags: docker

I read through the documentation of Docker Content Trust and some questions came up to the following scenario.
I start docker without having DCT enabled and deploy some images.
Then I decide to enable DCT so that I can only continue to deploy signed images.
What will happen to the unsigned ones that have already been deployed? Will they just continue running?

Can I somehow determine (being inside the application in the container and from host) if the image running is signed or unsigned?

Here is the documentation for [DCT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/trust/content_trust/)

Comment: Yes they will continue running and, as far as I know, determining if the image is signed or not only occurs during a `pull`. If I was more certain I would put this as an answer.

Comment: The pull can only be done with signed images, since the DCT makes it possible to see only signed images; and further from the documentation it also says that the commands `push`, `build`, `create`, `run` and `pull` are using DCT (I also added the relevant documentation now

Comment: You may want to do this to learn more: https://github.com/docker/labs/tree/master/security/trust

Comment: @MattSchuchard This shows the basic pushing and pulling of signed images as already described in the documentation I attached but doesn't help to answer the question, or did I miss something?

Comment: See also [How to pin public root key when downloading an image with docker pull (Docker Content Trust)?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/238916/how-to-pin-public-root-key-when-downloading-an-image-with-docker-pull-docker-co)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What will happen to the unsigned ones that have already been deployed? Will they just continue running?

If you pull images with docker content trust disabled, and then turn on docker content trust, nothing will happen to the existing images/containers.

The content trust operations are 100% a docker client implementation. The daemon doesn't really know nor care whether an image is signed.

If you have docker content trust enabled, and do a pull, create, or run, the client will look up the trust data and find the sha256 digest of the image that has been signed. The daemon then gets told that it's doing a pull/create/run of that digest.

> Can I somehow determine (being inside the application in the container and from host) if the image running is signed or unsigned?

Generally speaking, from inside a container, there is very little exposed. You can't return the image name, the container name, nor even the ports that are published. Even if you could, the daemon is blind to image signing, and only knows that it's been told to run a specific digest.

On the host you can determine whether a running container is using a signed image, but it isn't simply listed in 'docker images' or 'docker ps'. You would have to compare the image with the trust data. There isn't a pre-made UI component that does this for you that I'm aware of.

One thing to keep in mind is that signatures can be updated. Say I'm running ubuntu:14.04, which is a signed image. My container is up and running and all is well. Sooner or later the ubuntu:14.04 image will be updated, and new trust data will be published alongside the update of the image. Now, my container has an out of date image. The next time I go to do a docker pull/create/run, the updated trust data will be gotten, and I'll get the newer image. Part of what DCT guarantees is freshness.

Comment: What do you mean by "You would have to compare the image with the trust data"? To compare the currently assumed to be signed image in the container with the signed one from a registry?

Comment: You can look at the content trust data by running the correct notary lookup command. For example, if you want to see what the sha256 digest is of the ubuntu:14.04 image, you can run the following command: `notary -d ~/.docker/trust lookup docker.io/library/ubuntu 14.04`

You can compare that result to the RepoDigests data when you do a `docker inspect ubuntu:14.04`.

If they match, then you know you have the correct image.

Comment: Now that I think about it, you can also do another `docker pull ubuntu:14.04`, and that'll output the digest from the signed data, and say whether your engine already has the corresponding image. You would need to double check any running containers to see if they were started with that same image digest.

Answer (score 0):

```
docker trust inspect <image>
```

example: `docker trust inspect zookeeper`

```
[
    {
        "Name": "zookeeper",
        "SignedTags": [
            {
                "SignedTag": "3.3",
                "Digest": "0c5d4d56fb5b04d9a9212ef5971df194e1481df94eaf8ea6df1aa2bdf3fe9ad3",
                "Signers": [
                    "Repo Admin"
                ]
            },
            {
                "SignedTag": "3.3.6",
                "Digest": "0c5d4d56fb5b04d9a9212ef5971df194e1481df94eaf8ea6df1aa2bdf3fe9ad3",
                "Signers": [
                    "Repo Admin"
                ]
            },
            {
                "SignedTag": "3.4",
                "Digest": "3882d9493d387ba77b7b69e2a031b9396477ec29483d51ceaed645c1389182e5",
                "Signers": [
                    "Repo Admin"
                ]
            },
            {
                "SignedTag": "latest",
                "Digest": "b931ebcdb2efd5bc4cc3db9123ae3cddf7ba51cbe1a282a5ee750425b3ccd48d",
                "Signers": [
                    "Repo Admin"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "Signers": [],
        "AdministrativeKeys": [
            {
                "Name": "Root",
                "Keys": [
                    {
                        "ID": "bf41a27e3433dc9c65e68987ee5a7f9550b00ddfcfe8f9c2e16bdea76607c1f8"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Name": "Repository",
                "Keys": [
                    {
                        "ID": "84ac8dbd8ef8a604498f9d0cf7d2fd66e39f1e5d13bd0dc4ece33e5151666aad"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```